# how to use a component variable in my scss file in ionic3

Tags: css, angular, sass, ionic3

im trying to change my app theme color based on the user required theme color,for example i have multiple users and each user having their own app theme color,if a user loggedIn to my app then that user theme color has to apply to my whole app,so based on that theme value my app fonts and all the toggles need to change,  as of now i tried using `[ngStyle]` by calling the function fom my component like below

### home.html

```
<div [ngStyle]="setBgColor()">
  <p>{{myName}}</P>
  <p>{{myPlace}}</P>
  <p>{{myPhone}}</P>
</div>
```

### home.ts

```
 setBgColor(){
  return {'background-color': userThemeColor}
 }
```

but now i want to change the `ion-toggle` color and also for `ion-slides`pagination bullets color to the `userThemeColor`, how can i do it form them

### what i tried

`<ion-toggle (ionChange)="toggleChange()" [ngStyle]="setBgColor()"></ion-toggle>` 
here it is not changing for toggle, so now i want to export my theme color value to scss file and there i hve to use that color like below

```
.toggle-md .toggle-icon{
   background-color:{{userThemeColor}}
 }
```

Comment: you want to change theme only active page or full app page

Comment: full app pages @Utpaul

Comment: Did you check in css debugger why colors are not applied to your toggle? Are they overriden by something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As far I know, you can NOT use a dynamic variable in your scss file.**

*Alternative*: A (dirty) solution, with JQuery, would be:

**index.html**

```
<head>
  ...
  <style id="extraCSS" type="text/css"></style>
</head>
```

**custom.ts**

```
var customColor = 'rgb(255, 50, 50)';
var customColorWithTransparency = 'rgba(255, 50, 50, 0.75)';

$('#extraCSS').text(
    '.toggle-checked .toggle-icon { background-color: ' + customColorWithTransparency + ' !important;}' +
    '.toggle-checked .toggle-inner { background-color: ' + customColor + ' !important;}');
}
```

---

You can not change dynamically the `color` in `ion-toggle` or `ion-checkbox` at runtime. In opposite, you can set pre-defined (static) sass variable like this:

```
<ion-toggle color="somePredefinedColor"></ion-toggle>
```

…but, because you can not set a [hex-color-string](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/11754), this is impossible update `color` *directive* from server/API as hex-strings (for now).

Comment: it is not changing the color, returning color is not appending to the toggle @Mario Padilla

Comment: I updated the answer. First part shows you how update ion-toggle [color] dynamically. Second part explains how get a global 'scss' variable @Midhunsai

Comment: for me userCustomColor comes dynamically from api when user loggedIn, in your aanswer it is hardcoded in variable.scss, i need it change dynamically @Mario Padilla

Comment: @Midhunsai I updated the answer. I gave you a solution with JQuery. I tested it and it's working.